# Pop up in angular js using modal is not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am building a basic angular application in which I need to have a button which upon clicked should open a pop-up window and display the chart.

Here's my button which should render the pop up window.

```
<div style="padding-top:50px;padding-left:10px;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
Diagnose
</button>
</div>
```

Here's my pop-up window code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width:1140px;height:601px;left:70px;top:80px;border-radius:0px;">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:1140px;height:601px;margin:0px;border-radius:0px;">
<div class="modal-content" style="border-radius:0px;">
<div class="modal-header" style="padding: 18px 30px 18px 30px;">
<p class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="font-size:24px;color:#434343;float:left;">Correlation Plot</p>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float:right;">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="width:1140px;height:523px;overflow-y:auto;">
<div class="corrBox">

<span><p class="cardText">Top 4 correlated features with Parent Satisfaction</p></span>
</div>
<div class="corrInfoBox" >
<canvas baseChart height="80px"
[datasets]="corr_barChartData"
[labels]="['']"
[options]="corr_barChartOptions"
[legend]=true
[chartType]="corr_barChartType"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the plot appears in the screen without even clicking Diagnose button and nothing happens when I click the Diagnose button.

[image: Screen shot of my application]

How to link my click on the Diagnose button to display the bar plot in pop up window?

Comment: I suggest to use Angular based libraries like https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/ and https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home or https://www.primefaces.org

Answer (score 1):

Both your button and your pop-up are parts of the same parent component.
So assume you have the following:

- Current Page Component

  - Button
  - Pop-up

Your code will be designed as such
`currentPage.component.html`

`<button [etc] (onClick)="openPopup()">Button Text</button>`

```
currentPage.component.ts

public openPopup() {
     // your logic goes here
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to add your popup component's module inside your current page's module.

More information could have been provided had your question and code structure been clearer.